# Populating and submitting a Gravity Form on external site

Tags: php, post, curl, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two SEPARATE sites:

- Site A: A Wordpress site which has a Gravity Form.
- Site B: A non-Wordpress site which hosts a simple form - the data from this form needs to end up at Site A's Gravity Form (which also needs to auto-submit in this instance).

Can somebody tell me the easiest way to post data to and submit the form on Site A using a simple form on site B (if this is even possible)?